# Native Android - Poor malloc performance

Tags: android, performance, garbage-collection, native

At the start of my native Android program I malloc hundreds of blocks from a few K to a couple megs (but mostly on the smaller end). In the process, I get a long and fast list of these:

> GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 10% free 9116K/10044K, paused 10ms, total 10ms

I understand that this is normal behavior, but if possible, I'd like to reduce the frequency. The 10ms delays add up quickly when talking about app launch time. I'm wondering if there's a way to expand the heap more aggressively to avoid doing it over and over. Perhaps some sort of hinting mechanism?

I'd prefer not to guess ahead of time at how much the heap needs to grow and then force it with a large allocation (hoping for a solution that's not a hack). Worst comes to worst, I'll use a different C++ allocator to expand the free space more aggressively, but what a mess that would be. Any suggestions/recommendations?

Comment: I've just realize that I may be incorrectly assuming that it's the C mallocs that are causing this, when it could actually be Java objects being created and destroyed. My C++ code does create and destroy Java arrays in the process.

Comment: Yup.  The Dalvik GC is unaware of your native allocations.